# How do I highlight the number in a list that's closest to an integer in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Suppose I have a list of values like `3.67`, `15.89`, `8.58`, `1.14`, and `9.69` in 5 different cells.  How do I highlight the `15.89` since it's closest to an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in cells A1:A5, in cell B1 enter the following formula and fill down to B5:

```
=IF(MOD(A1,1)<0.5,MOD(A1,1),1-MOD(A1,1))
```

Now in cell B6 enter the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(SMALL(B1:B5,1),B1:B5,0)+0)
```

That'll give you the answer. If your data actually starts on say, row 7, then you'll need to update ranges accordiningly and also change the end of the 2nd formula from `+0` to `+6`.

We're using the modulo function to find the decimal value only... if the decimal is **under** 0.5 then we'll save that value; if it's **over** 0.5 we'll subtract it from 1: This makes the numbers comparable. Then the summary formula searches for the smallest result in column B, and uses the result cell's row to return the column A value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ready access to Excel to test using this solution with conditional formatting to highlight the cell, but here's the piece to identify the value closest to an integer.

[image]

Your values are in column A and identification of the closest is in column B.  You can adapt this as needed.

The solution is an array formula, so enter everything except the braces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The formula in B1 is:

```
=ABS(A1-ROUND(A1))=MIN(ABS($A$1:$A$5-ROUND($A$1:$A$5)))
```

Copy and paste as needed.  It compares the absolute difference between the value and its closest integer against the minimum for the range.  If the difference matches the minimum, it returns True.  So the result can be used as a test condition, or the basis to display, say, either a blank or some text for the closest one.